# Designing a Floor Plan for Restaurant in React and Tailwind

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to design and build the floor plan in react. But I cannot wrap my head around how I am going to make the page responsive with all those tables.
So far I have a modal, that adds the Rectangle Table and another Modal that adds the Circular table. Those look something like this,
[image: Rectangle Table Modal]

And, Circular table Modal
[image: Circular table Modal]

For the Floor plan itself, I have this,
[image: Floor Plan]

I am using this code to create that Floor Plan,

```
 <div
   className="border-gray-300 border shadow-2xl p-2"
   style={{ height: "900px", width: "100%" }}
  >
 </div>
```

Now when I add a new rectangle, how can I draw that rectangle inside this floor plan? And how can I make the floor plan responsive along with the tables that will be inside of it? I can add multiple rectangle and the circular table. And also, is dragging the tables and saving the x and y coordintaes of the tables possible?

I have this endpoint on my backend for saving the x and y coordinates, but I am not sure how the dragging will work on the frontend.

```
    @PutMapping("/update-coordinates/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> updateCoordinates(
        @PathVariable long id,
        @RequestBody UpdateRestaurantTableCoordinatesDTO updateRestaurantTableCoordinatesDTO
    ) {
          restaurantTableRepository.updateCoordinates(
              id,
              updateRestaurantTableCoordinatesDTO.xCoordinates,
              updateRestaurantTableCoordinatesDTO.yCoordinates
          );

        return ResponseUtils.ok();
    }
```

Comment: I strongly suggest you read about Canvas API at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API if you plan to build your own editor on pure html/js or you can read about Fabric.js at http://fabricjs.com/ and see how it can fit in your project.